# How to assign a hidden value to an output in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a site where you can assign importance to each question. There are 9 questions.

So if I want question 1 to be the most important then I would assign it as 1. 
If question 5 was the most important to me then I would assign that as 1 instead.

Importance of 1 needs to have a hidden value of 9 assigned to it. 
Importance of 2 needs to have a hidden value of 8 assigned to it.
etc, all the way to...
Importance of 9 needs to have a hidden value of 1 assigned to it.

The importance number is simply displayed in a span tag on screen but the hidden value will be used to create a multiplication in the backend.

How would I create this in jQuery?

I have inherited code but it doesn't do what I need it to. Instead it simply decreases the value by 1 for each question instead of allowing the user to define:

```
var importance = 9,
total = 0;

//Get the final calculations for each of the items
$('.unsorted-list .question-group').each(function(){
    total += parseInt($('.slider', $(this)).attr('value'),10)*importance*-1;
    importance--;
});
```

Comment: Adding code always helps get more people interested in helping you. It shows you have tried instead of just asking for code.

Comment: Definitely add your code

Comment: use a `data-` attribute like `data-importance="9"` . Show some html

Answer (score 0):

HTML code below-

```
<span data-val="10" id="rank">1</span>
```

JQUERY code -

```
 $("#rank").data("val")
```

Hope this helps http://jsfiddle.net/t8ssp84o/!

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if you think its right and it helped.